# Android Studio code completion suggestions very slow

Tags: android-studio

After an update to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 (Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443), the load timing for xml code suggestions went from milliseconds to 10s of seconds, if I hit Ctrl+Space it loads as it should.

I'm working on a sufficiently powerful machine (i5-10310U with 40GB RAM).

I tried disabling AI suggestions and other settings to ease the load times but it changed nothing.

Are there settings that control the load times of the code suggestions? Or anything that would help improve the load suggestion times?

Comment: Did you install the update using the Toolbox app? If yes, you can roll back a version with a single click, otherwise you could do that manually. Before doing that, anyway, you should [submit an issue](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/contribute/report-bugs#bug-queues) to the Android Studio team, as that is most likely a bug.

Comment: I tried everything and in the end I did a complete manual uninstall and removed every single trace of adb and platform-tools, then I installed an older version of android studio (v 2021.3.1). This solved my problem. There was an answer to my question detailing the steps necessary to fully remove Android Studio and every cache and component, but the author deleted it. This could be related to the fact that I had to remove nearly 105GB of cache. But I haven't tried to update since fearing the instability of the new builds.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. It is better to write in java language. Once using kotlin language, it will become slower and slower as the number of class files increases.
I found that the official knew about this problem several years ago, but did not give a clear plan

Comment: I don't really see how this relates to the question - he is talking about XML and, considering it worked fine the previous update, this is most likely a bug.